# why pip is not working in Kali linux. 22.4

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip

Pip is not working in my kali Linux 22.4.
Python3 and pip is the newest version installed. [prove of install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfSXK.jpg)
I am running my Kali Linux on VMware. kali is also the letest one.
While I install nummpy or anything by "pip" its through this error. [here is the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Nl9.jpg)

pip install PIL
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

```
If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
sure you have python3-full installed.

If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.
```

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

i was tring to install a library of python by pip but get this error. Manually i can install.

Comment: It’s very often you find `python3 -m pip` a more suitable way to go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me it worked by

> sudo apt-get install python-pkg

where "python-pkg" is the name your python package.

You can also try

> python3 -m pip install python-pkg

worked for me on a Mac.

Comment: how can you  install requirements.txt?